# Excel or VBA - VLOOKUP with IF Coniditon

Tags: excel, vba

> Hi,
>        I would like to investigate a huge list that I can distinguish the Acc numbers according to the mail adresses. The things that I
>   would like to do if email adresses has a seperate Acc and if they
>   equal each other( I mean if Acc numbers are equal),write a "equal" if
>   the criterias were not equal with the same email then write a
>   "multiple criteria"..

```
Is there any way to do that with Excel formulas or VBA ?


Mail                 Acc
uralsmh@gmail.com   C1234
uralsmh@gmail.com   C2345
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1 - check for duplicates**

Create a helper column that sticks columns A and B together and then count this column. You can use the `&` character for this:

```
     A     B     C         D
1    abc   123   =A1&B1    =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$1000,C1)
2    abc   123   =A2&C2    =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$1000,C2)
3    def   123   =A3&C3    =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$1000,C3)
```

If you get a number greater than `1` in column `D`, then that row is a duplicate of another row.

**Part 2 - find multiple accounts**
Now you have found the exact duplicates, any email addresses that match must have different account numbers. So, in column E, just count column A:

```
     A     B     C         D                           E
1    abc   123   =A1&B1    =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$1000,C1)   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,A1)
2    abc   123   =A2&C2    =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$1000,C2)   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,A2)
3    def   123   =A3&C3    =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$1000,C3)   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,A3)
```

If you get a number greater than `1` in column E and you had a `1` in column D, you have found an email address with multiple accounts.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot but this is not I want actually.. I do not want to find multiple accounts..I would like to distinguish the email adresses which has got a dfferent account numbers..I need to check the multiple criterias whether if they are same each other or not.. I need a non-equals.

Comment: @UgurYaman I'm not sure I understand your comment. You want to find email addresses that are the same and have multiple account numbers. That is what the process above will do.

Comment: I would like to find the email adresses which have multiple and different records.. For instance uralsmh has a 2 different Acc number. If those ACC number equal it is not necessary to distinguish..If that email has a different acc like as c123 c1234 I need to tag that email

Comment: That's what the method will do. For example, uralsmh has two different account numbers. It will be caught in part 2 above, where you find those email addresses with different account numbers. You are looking for a copy-and-paste VBA solution, when it is just simpler and easier to do this via a couple of helper columns in Excel.

Comment: I did it appreciate for your supports.